# Weird binding with Ember.Select value

Tags: ember.js

I'm having a weird issue with the Ember.Select view when I try to bind its value to a model.
Here is an abstract of what I'm doing, the complete jsbin can be found here:

Using JavaScript: http://jsbin.com/jayutuzazi/1/edit?html,js,output
Using CoffeeScript: http://jsbin.com/nutoxiravi/2/edit?html,js,output

Basically what I'm trying to do is use an attribute of a model to set an attribute of another model.

I have the `Age` model like this

```js
App.Age = DS.Model.extend({
  label: DS.attr('string'),
  base: DS.attr('number')
});
```

And an other model named `Person` like this

```js
App.Person = DS.Model.extend({
  name: DS.attr('string'),
  ageBase: DS.attr('number')
});
```

The template looks like this:

```
<!-- person/edit.hbs -->
<form>
  <p>Name {{input value=model.name}}</p>
  <p>
    Age
    {{view "select" value=model.ageBase
           content=ages
           optionValuePath="content.base"
           optionLabelPath="content.label"}}
  </p>
</form>
```

What I am trying to do is have a `select` in the Person edit form that lists the ages using `base` as value and `label` as label.

I expect the correct value to be selected when loading and to change when the selected option changes.

Has can be seen in the jsbin output, the selected is correctly populated but it sets the `ageBase` value of the edited person to `undefined` and does not select any option. The model value is correctly set when an option is selected though.

Am I doing something wrong ? Is it a bug ? What am I supposed to do to make this work ?

Thank you :)

Comment: Use JavaScript for your fiddles, everybody must know it and Coffee is something that some won't know. Reach the greater audience.

Comment: When does it get set to `undefined`? I don't see any buttons or save actions.

Comment: When the page is loaded. Before displaying the page a value is set. But when the page is displayed, the value is emptied and is only set again when an option is selected.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can conditionally render based on fulfilment of the `ages` as follows, since select doesn't handle promises (more on that below):

```
{{#if ages.isFulfilled}}
    {{view "select" value=ageBase
           content=ages
           optionValuePath="content.base"
           optionLabelPath="content.label"}}
{{/if}}
```

I updated your [JsBin](http://jsbin.com/papogocizo/2/edit?html,css,js,output) demonstrating it working.

I also illustrate in the JsBin how you don't have to qualify with `model.` in your templates since object controllers are proxies to the models they decorate.  This means your view doesn't have to be concerned with if a property comes from the model or some computed property on the controller.

There is currently a [PR #9468](https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/pull/9468) for select views which I made a case for getting merged into Ember which addresses some issues with selection and option paths.  There is also [meta issue #5259](https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/issues/5259) to deal with a number of select view issues including working with promises.

From issue #5259 you will find that Ember core developer, Robert Jackson, has some candidate select replacements.  I cloned one into this [JsBin](http://emberjs.jsbin.com/wofila/1/edit) running against latest production release version of Ember.

There is nothing at all preventing you using Roberts code as a select view replacement in your app.  Asynchronous collections/promises will just work (and it is MUCH faster rendering from the benchmarks I have seen).

The template for that component is just:

```
{{#if prompt}}
  <option disabled>{{prompt}}</option>
{{/if}}

{{#each option in resolvedOptions}}
  <option {{bind-attr value=option.id}}>{{option.name}}</option>
{{/each}}
```

The js of the component is:

```
App.AsyncSelectComponent = Ember.Component.extend({
  tagName: 'select',
  prompt: null,

  options: null,
  initialValue: null,

  resolvedOptions: null,
  resolvedInitialValue: null,

  init: function() {
    var component = this;

    this._super.apply(this, arguments);

    Ember.RSVP.hash({
      resolvedOptions: this.options,
      resolvedInitialValue: this.initialValue
    })
      .then(function(resolvedHash){
        Ember.setProperties(component, resolvedHash);

        //Run after render to ensure the <option>s have rendered
        Ember.run.schedule('afterRender', function() {
          component.updateSelection();
        });
      });
  },

  updateSelection: function() {
    var initialValue = Ember.get(this, 'resolvedInitialValue');
    var options = Ember.get(this, 'resolvedOptions') || [];
    var initialValueIndex = options.indexOf(initialValue);
    var prompt = Ember.get(this, 'prompt');

    this.$('option').prop('selected', false);

    if (initialValueIndex > -1) {
      this.$('option:eq(' + initialValueIndex + ')').prop('selected', true);
    } else if (prompt) {
      this.$('option:eq(0)').prop('selected', true);
    }
  },

  change: function() {
    this._changeSelection();
  },

  _changeSelection: function() {
    var value = this._selectedValue();

    this.sendAction('on-change', value);
  },

  _selectedValue: function() {
    var offset = 0;
    var selectedIndex = this.$()[0].selectedIndex;

    if (this.prompt) { offset = 1; }

    return Ember.get(this, 'resolvedOptions')[selectedIndex - offset];
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that in:

```
{{view "select" value=model.ageBase
```

When the app starts, `value` is undefined and `model.ageBase` gets synchronized to that before `value` is synchronized to `model.ageBase`. So, the workaround is to skip that initial undefined `value`.

See: http://jsbin.com/rimuku/1/edit?html,js,console,output

The relevant parts are:

template

```
{{view "select" value=selectValue }}
```

controller

```
App.IndexController = Ember.Controller.extend({

  updateModel: function() {
    var value = this.get('selectValue');
    var person = this.get('model');

    if ( value ) { // skip initial undefined value
      person.set('ageBase', value);
    }
  }.observes('selectValue'),

  selectValue: function() {
    // randomly used this one
    return this.store.find('age', 3);
  }.property()

});
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I thought of this but felt a bit dirty adding every bound value on the controller and all. IMHO it somewhat defeats the point of having Ember.Select in the first place. Has you say it's a workaround, should it be necessary?

Comment: Why is it dirty? Actually the controller is where you should be placing your binds. The controller is a decorator for your models and the place where you want to perform this type of logic.

Comment: It's dirty because I don't have to do it when dealing with the name attribute for instance. I don't think it's related to value being undefined but more with the fact that ages is a promise. Trying with a hard coded array works out of the box :/

Comment: Well of course, `value` is undefined at first **because** its data comes from a promise and it is populated until that promise is resolved...

Comment: Not the one from `model`. When I used `{{log model.ageBase}}` the value was not `undefined`. Only the `ages` part was `undefined`. When I hard coded data I only hard coded `ages`, not `person`.

Answer (score 0):

givanse's answer should work.

I don't think it's because value is undefined, but because value is just an integer (42) and not equal to any of the selects content, which are Person objects ({ id: 2, label: 'middle', base: 42 }).

You could do something similar to what givens suggests or use relationships.

### Models

```
//
// Models
//

App.Person = DS.Model.extend({
  name: DS.attr('string'),
  ageBase: DS.belongsTo('age', { async: true })
});

App.Age = DS.Model.extend({
  label: DS.attr('string'),
  base: DS.attr('number')
});

//
// Fixtures
//

App.Person.reopenClass({
  FIXTURES: [
    { id: 1, name: 'John Doe', ageBase: 2 }
  ]
});

App.Age.reopenClass({
  FIXTURES: [
    { id: 1, label: 'young',  base: 2  },
    { id: 2, label: 'middle', base: 42 },
    { id: 3, label: 'old',    base: 82 }
  ]
});
```

### Template:

```
<h1>Edit</h1>

<pre>
  name: {{model.name}}
  age: {{model.ageBase.base}}
</pre>

<form>
  <p>Name {{input value=model.name}}</p>
  <p>
    Age
    {{view "select" value=model.ageBase
           content=ages
           optionValuePath="content"
           optionLabelPath="content.label"}}
  </p>
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks but I don't want a Person related to an Age. I only want to set the baseAge according to a selected Age.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I found a solution that I think is more satisfying. As I thought the issue was coming from `ages` being a promise. The solution was to ensure that the ages list was loaded **before** the page was rendered.

Here is how I did it:

```
App.IndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function() {
    return Ember.RSVP.hash({
      person: this.store.find('person', 1),
      ages: this.store.findAll('age')
    });
  }
});
```

That's it! All I need from there is to change the view according the new model:

```
{{#with model}}
  <form>
    <p>Name {{input value=person.name}}</p>
    <p>
      Age
      {{view "select" value=person.ageBase
             content=ages
             optionValuePath="content.base"
             optionLabelPath="content.label"}}
    </p>
  </form>
{{/with}}
```

The complete working solution can be found here: http://jsbin.com/qeriyohacu/1/edit?html,js,output

Thanks again to @givanse and @Larsaronen for your answers :)

Comment: I'm glad you found another option. Note that this actually changes the intent of the original question. If you were to display the results of another `person` (change de model), with every change you would be retrieving `age`s again and again.

Comment: Indeed, it still send a request to get the data but the binding is working. The only thing I need to change is the way I get the ages so that it only fires a request when it's necessary :)

Comment: This doesn't work well for a couple of reasons. The controller won't have its ``model`` property set (suggest changing ``person`` to ``model`` and use ``setProperties`` with the RSVP hash in your routes ``setupController`` hook).  Also when you want to use say ``{{link-to 'person/edit' somePerson}}`` or use ``transitionTo``/``transitionToRoute`` with a model, the routes ``model`` hook won't be called and the related ages collection won't be fetched.

Comment: To address the ages fetching problem in my previous comment consider hoisting the ages to a higher route (even the application route) and either using needs in your controller or using setupController with modelFor to obtain the ages and set them.

Comment: Actually I used `setupController` in my application to set the controller model properly and the rest as properties. Thanks for the recommendation on fetching ages.